# Notification count and new items in inbox count mismatches when user comments twice on same thread

Tags: bug

Whenever I got a new item in inbox, I generally saw a number of new notifications on inbox button in left top bar. However this number of new notification is sometimes counted wrongly. This happens when same person comments more then once on same thread.

Commenting somewhere logs one comment event in inbox. Whenever new comment is placed on the same question/answer and user haven't read last comment then lastly logged comment in inbox is replaced by new one. This way no of new notification is equals to number of times someone commented on that particular questions/answers but number of new message in inbox is only one.

In my case this happens when someone commented twice on same answer. I don't know what happens when different users comments.

Comment: How should it behave? Show only `1` in the notifications icon or show both comments when you open the notifications box.

Comment: Of course, if someone comments twice on the same post, you are going to end up seeing both anyways...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Usually, but sometimes the first comment is short enough to read in the inbox (e.g., "Thank you, @poster!") and you don't bother clicking through to the post.

Comment: But then the discrepancy between "number x+y in notification" and "x visible messages in the dropdown" would be sufficient to prompt you to click through.  When *x* is large, it's hard to know which one to click through to, though; and I imagine for large *y* and *x* >> 1 it's going to be really bewildering. But then again, if you have been away for that long, you probably want to click through on all comments anyway just to refresh your memory of what was being discussed, in which case one click-through per conversation is actually a useful feature.

Comment: @ArtjomB. My suggestion is to show both comments in inbox.

Comment: @tripleee ok then for large x at least inbox shows an expand button that will show/hide all the comments by a user on that particular thread.